# RStudio-only error with tcl/tk?

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit, rstudio

When I compute an ROC plot with the package `pROC`, I get the following error in RStudio v. 99.9.9:

```
## Loading required package: tcltk

## Warning: couldn't connect to display ":0"

## Error: [tcl] invalid command name "toplevel".
```

I thought this was an issue in my OS (Debian with r-base 3.1 installed from APT depending on tcl/tk lib version 8.5), but when evaluating the same code through the terminal, I get the plot rendered without the same error.

Here is a simple example following some `pROC` example code that will generate the error when knitted in RStudio, but works in vanilla R:

````
```{r markdown.test}
library(pROC)
features <- runif(25)
labels <- as.factor(runif(25) < 0.75)
lda.model <- lda(as.matrix(features),labels)
lda.pred <- predict(lda.model,as.matrix(features))

lda.roc <- plot.roc(lda.pred$posterior[,1],
                    c(labels),
                    ci=TRUE, of="se", #specificities = seq(0,100,5),
                    ci.type="shape",
                    ci.col="#1c61b6AA")
```
````

The error occurs when the confidence interval parameters are added to the call.

Is there something missing from my RStudio install/config, or is this a bug?

Comment: Confidence intervals as in `[A…B]`?

Comment: @DonalFellows Yup, the function specifically computes a polygon from the confidence intervals computed over the input (posterior probabilities) and adds it to the plot. The line generated by calling it without those parameters plots without error.

Answer (score 0):

Blast from the past!  I see that same error today on an instance of RStudio installed in the IBM computing environment called CP4D. Did you ever find an answer?

I think the way to fix on your Macintosh is to install Quartz and let it serve as the X11 server to display output from programs like tcltk or maybe even hist() or quartz() devices. (my team wrote install instructions https://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/crmda_guides/47.mac_R_setup).

I'm not sure what I'll do on the CP4D thing, since it is running inside a Web browser.

Comment: Tk on macOS can be built in two ways, either for Aqua (native) or X11; this is selected by the value of the `--enable-aqua` option to `configure` (respectively `yes` or `no`). _Both of these are supported options,_ at least up to Catalina. I guess I'll get around to checking Big Sur in a few days…

Comment: The point is… Tk can either work natively or with X11 (which is implemented with Xquartz on macOS; there's a few ways to get it).